# im having trouble adding a new command to my bot but it has a type error "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Tags: discord.js, execute

im trying to add a new command to my bot but i have the issue of when the command is being executed, it logs an error in the terminal of it not being able to read 'execute'. here is the error code:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
at Client. < anonymous > (C: \Users\ brand\ scoot.js\ scoot.js: 45: 38)
at Client.emit(node: events: 378: 20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ discord.js\ src\ client\ actions\ MessageCreate.js: 31: 14)
at Object.module.exports[as MESSAGE_CREATE](C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ discord.js\ src\ client\ websocket\ handlers\ MESSAGE_CREATE.js: 4: 32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ discord.js\ src\ client\ websocket\ WebSocketManager.js: 384: 31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ discord.js\ src\ client\ websocket\ WebSocketShard.js: 444: 22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ discord.js\ src\ client\ websocket\ WebSocketShard.js: 301: 10)
at WebSocket.onMessage(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ ws\ lib\ event - target.js: 132: 16)
at WebSocket.emit(node: events: 378: 20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage(C: \Users\ brand\ node_modules\ ws\ lib\ websocket.js: 825: 20)
```

and here is my index.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const fs =require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const prefix = '!';



const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`); 
    

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
} 









client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Scoot Is Now Online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if(command === 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
        
    } 
    else if (command == 'fortnitecomp'){
        client.commands.get('fortnitecomp').execute(message.args);
    
    }


});




















client.login('my token');
```

and this is my command module for the "fortnitecomp"

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'fortnitecomp',
    description: "this command sends a youtube compilation of fortnite (:",
    execute(message, args){

              

      message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3gZi62iefo')
    }
}
```

what should i be doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
client.commands.get('fortnitecomp').execute(message.args);
```

should be

```
client.commands.get('fortnitecomp').execute(message, args);
```

Please consider upvoting this post if it works

Comment: Hey! So i changed that part, thats my bad. But i do still end up with the same error code of "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Comment: I just tried and it works perfectly fine. Let me try again

Comment: @EDP445 Do you have a folder named "commands" with a file inside of your commands folder named "fortnitecomp.js"

Comment: Yes, i have done that. but i still get the same error in the terminal @Alex0754

Comment: Yeah, keep getting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

FOUND WHAT WAS WRONG!

https://travis-scoot.anti-jew.club/tjNJhq9H

in that screenshot, the bottom code was the working one, and the one on top was the bad code, i dont know exactly what happened but i got it to work now!